# ASP.Net C# generate and download PDF File

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm trying to generate and download a pdf file. It keeps saying that the file type is wrong or that the file is damaged.

Here is my code

```
 protected void downloadFile(int index)
    {

        string strContent = "<html> <body> <div> <b> Tjeu! </b> </div> <div> <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME=\"maillist\" disabled=\"disabled\">Yes! Put me on the list! </div> </body> </html>";
        string attach = "attachment; filename=wordtest.pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attach);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strContent);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
```

Thx for the help ;)

Comment: When you open an existing PDF file in notepad (for instance) you're not going to see HTML. Renaming an HTML file to .PDF does not make it a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Because `strContent` is an HTML string, not the contents of a PDF file.

PDF has a format of its own and isn't so easily created by the means you expect to use here, and, in fact, even dedicating yourself to programming a 'PDF Writer' would be quite a feat of work - there are already people who have worked / are working on this, so, if you really need PDF, I'd suggest you use a third-party library.

Here's one, for example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/

Comment: How does a content of a pdf file looks like? I have to generate checkboxes and other html stuff

Comment: Use some thirdparty tools to create the PDF file. iTextSharp is a good pick.http://itextsharp.com/

Comment: @Evert: Is there a requirement to use PDF? Can't you use HTML?